# Bulk XML upload for Google Blogger API

Tags: python, api, client, blogger

All,

I'm trying to find a way to overcome the 50 post rate limit of the Google Blogger API using the Google Python client library. The CreatePost() method fails after exactly 50 posts with a "gdata.client.RequestError: Server responded with: 400, Blog has exceeded rate limit or otherwise requires word verification for new posts" error message. It appears, however, that there may be a lower level bulk upload solution using an XML POST containing multiple blog entries. Although an example is provided in the Blogger API documentation for the XML syntax, the API is unclear how to implement a bulk upload within the context of the Python client API.

Can anyone provide any insight into this problem?